# Sharing to Hyper-V without requiring credentials

Tags: virtual-machine, file-sharing

I'm running Windows 8 on a domain joined machine (i have local admin, not domain admin). I have VM's on hyper-v and I want to share a folder without requiring the VM's to logon. The VM's are setup on a internal network.

I've shared a folder with read perms for "Everyone" and when I try to access it from the VM's it always asks for credentials.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you give your user specific access instead of using "Everyone"?

Comment: I don't know how that would work. My host machine is domain joined and the VM's are not. I'm logging into all of them as Administrator. I tried giving administrators access but it still asks for credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2003/XPSP2 the Everyone group does not include the Anonymous/Guest account.

You can edit the security policies of the domain (or the local security polices of each non-domain-joined VM in your case) via `secpol.msc` to include that Anonymous account back in.

The policy to change/enable is `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Security Options\Network Access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users`.

You can get the same effect by modifying the registry directly:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\EveryoneIncludesAnonymous` - set it to 1 (REG_DWORD) to enable the rule.